# How to setAttribute on React JSX element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iteration, jsx, setattribute

I want to set `key` attribute on React element dynamically, like below. However both approaches do not work. I know I can use other technique for that, but I'd like to know if it is possible to do so this way:

One:

```
{
    new Array(3).fill(<td></td>).map((td,i) => {
        td.setAttribute('key', i);
        return td;
    })
}
```

Two:

```
{
    new Array(3).fill(document.createElement(td)).map((td,i) => {
        td.setAttribute('key', i);
        return td;
    })
}
```

The error

```
// td is {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "td", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
// Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: td.setAttribute is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those put the **same** `td` element in the array three times. Definitely not what you want to do. You want to create *three* `td`s. You could do that by filling with `null` and then mapping in the elements:

```
{
    Array(3).fill(null).map((_, i) => <td key={i}></td>)
}
```

or using `Array.from`'s callback:

```
{
  Array.from(Array(3), (_, i) => <td key={i}></td>)
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const Row = () =>
  <tr>
    {
      Array.from(Array(3), (_, i) => <td key={i}>TD #{i}</td>)
    }
  </tr>
;

ReactDOM.render(
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <Row />
    </tbody>
  </table>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```